# How to delete mongoose's documents older than 24 hours in express js server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Im coding up an app that uses ExpressJS server and mongoose to handle MongoDB.

I will receive some measurements from external sensors and I will be storing them in the db. I will be only using measurements from last 24 hours.

Is there a way to somehow automatically delete documents from Mongo that are older than 24 hours? Every measurement document will have a field called `createdAt` containing the exact date when it has been created.

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at [mongoose-ttl](https://github.com/mongoosejs/mongoose-ttl)

Comment: [**`db.yourcollection.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 86400})`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-after-a-specified-number-of-seconds). Downvoted question for failing to use Google and [reading the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-after-a-specified-number-of-seconds)

Comment: @Stu I tried using it and it does not work. I see a field called `__ttl` in the document, but it does not get reaped.

Comment: @AleksanderSadaj Maybe open a new question with the specifics of what you are trying - including the code you have written etc?

Comment: @Stu I did that, here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340312/expressjs-socket-hang-up-after-mongoose-ttl-or-basic-mongodb-ttl-reaps

Comment: @AleksanderSadaj I had a look at your new question and upvoted. I can't really think of anything to help though. Its really difficult to say what the problem could be as there is so little information to go on. Sorry!

Comment: @Stu If there is any information I could give you just tell me and I will provide it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use time-to-live(TTL) index on a date field like `createdOn` or `addedOn` in your collection with expiry seconds, eveny document you insert should have this field with current system time `new Date()`

The documents will be deleted after the expiry seconds automatically in the background

[TTL index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/index.html)

creating index on date field

```
> db.sensor.ensureIndex({'addedOn' : 1} , { expireAfterSeconds: 24*60*60 // 1 day})
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

index

```
> db.sensor.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "test.sensor"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "addedOn" : 1
        },
        "name" : "addedOn_1",
        "ns" : "test.sensor",
        "expireAfterSeconds" : 86400
    }
]
>
```

Example (with expire in 20s)

insert into collection

```
> db.sensor.insert({machineId : 'dc-rack123-1243', addedOn : new Date()})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
>
```

system time

```
> new Date()
ISODate("2018-01-14T14:05:18.008Z")
>
```

document

```
> db.sensor.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a5b639942005c0824b9c983"), "machineId" : "dc-rack123-1243", "addedOn" : ISODate("2018-01-14T14:05:13.064Z") }
>
```

after 20+seconds, document deleted from collection

```
> new Date()
ISODate("2018-01-14T14:08:39.436Z")
> db.sensor.find()
>
```

Comment: this code goes into `mongo` itself, right? Do I specify it in the db terminal once and Im good? Or should I implement that in the code somehow?

Comment: Yes, we need to index collection on server side, after TTL the documents will be deleted by a daemon, ensure all the documents we insert should have the date or timestamp field to represent the insertion time and indexed

Comment: for the date or timestamp field, you can set default `currentDate` value, please see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/#example